# VUE/NUXT: Pass random number as props to child component

Tags: vue.js, components, nuxt.js

I want to have a randomNumber variable inside a vue component. But in my template and in my script tag, the values never match.

using datas:

```html
<template>
 <div :data-number="randomNumber"
</template>
<script>
export default {
 data (){
  return { randomNumber: Math.random() * 1000}
 },
 mounted: function(){
  console.log(this.randomNumber)
 }
}
</script>
```

using computed property:

```html
<template>
 <div :data-number="randomNumber"
</template>
<script>
export default {
 computed{
  randomNumber: Math.random() * 1000
 },
 mounted: function(){
  console.log(this.randomNumber)
 }
}
</script>
```

Or passing the randomNumber as props from my parent component.

I expect data-number to be equal to this.randomNumber, but it's never the case.

I managed to get a workaround for my project, but I'm still interested in the solution here.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks !

Comment: I tried your component in some fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Al_un/xwrpn2ea/. The only difference is that I also display the value inside my `div` but it does work for me. My console display proper values so I don't see where is the problem (-_-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to first initialize randomNumber variable number as null, then assign a value in the **mounted()** method like:

**Main Component**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{randomNumber}}
   <ChildComp :randomNum="randomNumber"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComp from './components/ChildComp'
export default {
  name: "App",
  data (){
    return { 
      randomNumber: null
    }
 },
 mounted: function(){
  this.randomNumber = Math.random() * 1000
 },
 components: {
   ChildComp
 }
};
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```html
<template>
  <div>{{randomNum}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildComp",
  props: {
    randomNum: Number
  }
};
</script>
```

This gives the same output every time like

```
190.9193234159494
190.9193234159494
```

Because you don't know how many times your data or computed functions trigger and initialize the variable.

Comment: To my understanding, the way you design your Main component sounds exactly like the need of computed properties

Comment: Correct, it can be achieved with the computed properties as well. Actually there is no problem when I tried the code that Vincent wrote, maybe some other code breaks his app, I thought initializing variable in mounted method is more reliable since it will be called only once.